# What do people mean when they say that the "Fundamental Theorem of Engineering" is $\pi=3=e$?

Tags: pi

I've seen this kind of thing on many sites, that the "Fundamental Theorem of Engineering" is

$$\pi=3=e$$

Some of them said this is just a joke.

Well, I know $\pi=3,1415926\ldots$ and $e=2,7128128459045\ldots$

Then, what is the idea behind what did they thinking about?

Is this about "Rounding Numbers"?

Comment: The joke is that engineers are not precise.  Physicists are not always rigorous, and mathematicians are punctilious.

Comment: Physicists have more or less the same saying -- google "spherical cow"

Comment: Can't help recalling [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill).

Comment: Check the decimal expansion of $e$ , two eights are missing.

Comment: @MaxChan I agree, but off-topic questions are far more upvoted many times and moreover receive many answers , also upvoted many times than down- or close- or even delete-voted. Maybe, as a side note, it is worth mentioning that in the USA around $1900$ (I do not remember the exact year) , $\pi$ has been defined by law as $4$ , which should be less accurate than any approximation that is used in practice.

Comment: I know! Roman defines pi as 3 1/8 or even 4 sometimes!